# update content in 2 browsers AFTER submit

Tags: php, jquery

If I have the following the text updates in 2 browsers normally:

index.php
    
    
    Send

```
function getStatus() {
    $.post('update.php', function(data) {
        $('div.text_window').html(data);
    });
    setTimeout("getStatus()",1000);
}

getStatus();
```

update.php

```
echo 'some text';
```

But if I cancel the automatic call to function on page load, and assign it to happen when a button is clicked (the following code), it updates in the browser where it was clicked, but how do I make it update in the other browser as well?

```
$('#send_btn').click(function() {
    getStatus();
});
```

Comment: update in other browser ? you can issue a regular request to server to check whether there are updates. If yes, show it.

Comment: I'm guessing you want something like stackoverflow has, when you new post is submitted you will see a pop-up showing that there are new posts (ofc instead of the popup it should just update it directly). For could use something like this http://socket.io/. Ofc an esier way is to just send a request at the server to see if there are any new posts

Comment: @Spokey I think he is already updating at regular internal of 1 sec, so other browser should automatically reflect the changes

Answer (score 0):

It seems your issue is related to availability of jQuery, put your initial call function in callback

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    getStatus();
});
```

Also make sure to increase your timeout, It should be 5-10 seconds

If you want instant updates and want to do it efficiently, you need to use PubSub or WebSockets

Answer (score -1):

Because you have to make da preventDefault action,
there is two way to do that.

with return false (the better way)

```
$('#send_btn').click(function() {
    getStatus();
    return false;
})
```

Or with event.preventDefault() (bleah)

```
$('#send_btn').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    getStatus();
})
```

Read on the http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/ for more info

Comment: Another advice, if you are in to a form, don't use the event click of the button, but the $('form').submit() event ;)